# IOS: textField now formatting entry as a phone number throughout app

Tags: ios, textfield

I used the method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

to format some phone numbers that are typed into a textfield.

I have now noticed that my login screen which uses textFields has suddenly begun formatting the userid and password as phone numbers as well making it impossible to log in.

Can I infer from this that if you use the above method, it affects all textFields in your app?

If so, is there a workaround to only use it for phone numbers?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Are you using the same delegate for every text field in your app?

Comment: not a delegate protocol but I have this method in  a core view controller where I put various commonly used methods from which most view controllers inherit.  I am very fuzzy on what methods get called automatically.   If I change (BOOL)textField:textField to textField:myPhoneTextField would this narrow it down to only the textField I want?

Comment: I was able to fix this by changing the method to (BOOL)textField:textField to textField:myPhoneTextField and setting myPhoneTextField.delegate = self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 suggestions.

1. Use textFieldShouldBeginEditing to set a class var, here called "activeTextField", then in shouldChangeCharactersInRange compare with your text field

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        activeTextField = textField
        return true
    }

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


    if (textField == textPhono) {
        //do your logic
    }
}
```

2. Mark all of your phone text fields with especific tag for phones, then compare tag in "shouldChangeCharactersInRange"

Comment: Suggestion #1 works like a charm especially if you also want to set different formatting for other textfields as well

Comment: That is probably a good way to do it so I marked it correct although for my purposes I just changed the name of the textfield in the delegate method as in the comment above to myPhoneField to make it specific to the phone number textfield.  The downside of my approach is I will have to repeat the code for each phone textfield.  If you have a chance to translate yours to objective-c would appreciate it.